# Как в цикл for (cmd) объединить вот эти три цикла?

Tags: cmd, for

## Чего только не перепробовал, но остановился на этой версии, которая тоже не работает:

```
for /l %%i in (%1\*.%4, %2\*.%4, %3\*.%4)  do 
( 
  if "%1\.%4" == "%%i" (7z a task\arch_%4 "%%i")
  else (if "%2\.%4" == "%%i" (7z a task\arch_%4 "%%i"))
  else (if "%3\.%4" == "%%i" (7z a task\arch_%4 "%%i"))
)
```

## Версия с тремя циклами:

```
for %%i in (%1\*.%4, %2\*.%4, %3\*.%4)  do 7z a task\arch_%4 "%%i"
for %%i in (%1\*.%5, %2\*.%5, %3\*.%5)  do 7z a task\arch_%5 "%%i"
for %%i in (%1\*.%6, %2\*.%6, %3\*.%6)  do 7z a task\arch_%6 "%%i"
```

Comment: Что в переменных? Пробелы или какие-то особые символы есть, или только латиница?

Comment: Первые три переменные - это папки. Три остальных переменные - это расширение. Прошу прощения, что не указал раньше.

Comment: Вопрос про допустимые символы по-прежнему актуален.

Comment: Файлы либо пусты(docx, txt), либо же заполнены таким же кодом, что я указал. Зависит от расширения. Но я пробовал только bat, docx, txt ,rtf

Comment: Перечитай мой вопрос.

Comment: В переменных присутствуют знаки Ланитиницы(например, название папок Material, Temp, Task. Название файлов тоже все на латинице, используется "_" ). Единственное, папки в которых все эти файлы лежат имеют название на латинице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в расширениях нет пробелов, то вот так:

```
for %%e in (%4 %5 %6) do for %%f in (%1\*.%%e, %2\*.%%e, %3\*.%%e) do echo arch_%%e "%%f"
```